# Using PHP simplexml parsing

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to parse some XML from a link, but to update the link to pull the correct item information, comes from the correct `$product_id`.

The goal is to click a button (a `$product_id` number is set to each button) and then it will show the `product` information that I parse onto that same page or a different page into a `table` (think of an add-to-cart button and shopping cart display).

I have the following defined globally, but I am not sure if the `$product_id` variable is being used properly for the link:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("https://secure.bmtmicro.com/cart?CID=2/WP&PRODUCTID=' . $product_id . '");
```

I've been trying to call `$xml` inside of a function that should output the information, but it's not working, so I just want to start my troubleshooting from the beginning. Is `simplexml_load_file()` even the best way to pull from a URL and if so, am I even setting up the variable properly?
(I am fairly new to PHP). Thanks in advance!

The function that I'm using to try and show the product information is:

```
function print_cart($args = array()) { 
  #some other code that doesn't involve the $xml

    if ($_SESSION['simpleCart'] && is_array($_SESSION['simpleCart'])){
      $output .= '
        <tr class="cart_item_row">
        <th class="cart_item_name_th">' . (__("Product Name")) . '</th><th class"bmt_cart_qty_th">' . (__("quantity")) . '</th><th class="cart_price_th">' . (__("Price")) . '</th><th></th>
        </tr>';

        foreach ($xml->children() as $product) {
            echo $product->productname;
        }

    $output .= "</table></div>";
    $output = apply_filters('after_cart_output', $output);
    return $output;
}
```

This is the original XML content (using random product id and its info):

```
<shoppingcart>
  <producttable>
    <row number="0">
      <productid>22804</productid>
      <productname>XFree86 CD</productname>
      <quantity>1</quantity>
      <productprice>$15.00</productprice>
      <discount>$0.00</discount>
      <rowtotal>$15.00</rowtotal>
    </row>
    <row number="1">
      <productid>193</productid>
      <productname>Testproduct - Remote Key Generator</productname>
      <quantity>1</quantity>
      <productprice>$0.99</productprice>
      <discount>$0.50</discount>
      <rowtotal>$0.49</rowtotal>
    </row>
  </producttable>
</shoppingcart>
```

Comment: Basics to start with, if $xml is false - then it's failed to load.  Otherwise try `echo $xml->asXML();` to see the data you've retrieved.

Comment: what happens when you var_dump on $xml?

Comment: var_dump on a SimpleXMLElement object is very hit and miss (usually it missed out all sorts of data).

Comment: @NigelRen later down in the function I have `foreach ($xml->children() as $product) { echo $product->productname; }`. Productname is the first tag I want to pull

Comment: Probably easier to add some more code to the question, give more specific detail to what your after and what you have so far.

Comment: @NigelRen I will try and edit the post to add more detail. Might take a few minutes.

Comment: @NigelRen I added some more of the code. Does it help?

Comment: Could do with a sample of the XML content

Comment: @NigelRen Edited (again)

Answer (score 1):

Your `foreach` is probably picking up the wrong elements.  When you use `->children()`, this is every child element of the start point.  This isn't always what you want.  What this code does is loop over the producttable elements and then the row elements within that (which is where the `->producttable->row` comes from)

```
foreach ( $xml->producttable->row as $product ) {
    echo $product->productname.PHP_EOL;
}
```

With your sample data, this gives...

```
XFree86 CD
Testproduct - Remote Key Generator
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought maybe that was the reason the buttons aren't displaying, but it appears there might be an issue somewhere else. I have added your code and will try to debug what else is going on

Comment: @JeffBerlin I don't see anywhere in your code that you tried to display a button

Comment: @MaxJones yeah, I didn't display code for that because I thought this XML was the issue. It's for wordpress and I believe it has to do with a shortcode somewhere.